# Do Schengen Embassies respond with letters?

Tags: schengen, belgium, estonia

I applied for a Schengen VISA to Estonia via Belgium Embassy (Represents Estonia in my country). I got the message below from VFS after 11 days..

> Please be informed that the Embassy of Belgium in Lagos has finalized your application.
>   VFS has been informed that the letter that the Belgium Embassy has addressed to you has been sent to them and will arrive at your Visa Application Centre very soon.
>
> They will personally inform you as soon your letter reaches the Visa Application Centre and is ready for collection or, if you have opted for this service, will be sent by UPS.
>
> If you have opted for the return of this letter by UPS, VFS will forward it immediately to UPS for delivery. You can track your letter with the UPS Waybill number you have received at the time of submission of your file.

Please what does this email translates to...?

Comment: It means the decision has been made and sent to the VAC, who will advise you when it is available for you to collect. It doesn’t indicate whether you’ve been given the visa or not, you’ll have to wait until you go to the VAC to find out the decision.

Comment: It sounds strange that VFS would speak of themselves as "they" ... are you sure you have the right understanding of who this message is from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm what do you think it translates to...?